# 401 Error before being trying to login in browser form Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, basic-authentication

When I try to open my `localhost:8080` spring security basic auth application, I get a 401 Unauthorized error before I get the chance to authenticate using the spring form login. It works fine in Postman since I can provide the authentication details when I call the url.
Heres my SecurityFilterChain:

```
@Bean
public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http.authorizeHttpRequests((authorizeHttpRequests) ->
                        authorizeHttpRequests
                                .requestMatchers("/admin/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
                                .requestMatchers("/**").hasRole("USER"))
                .formLogin(withDefaults())
                .httpBasic(withDefaults())
                .exceptionHandling((exceptionhandling) ->
                        exceptionhandling
                                .accessDeniedHandler(new CustomDeniedHandler()))
                .exceptionHandling(ex ->
                        ex.authenticationEntryPoint((request, response, authenticationException) ->{

                            // TODO: Find a way to replace "unknown intruder" with the real name of the user

                            String username = "unknown intruder";

                            if(authenticationException instanceof BadCredentialsException){
                                username = request.getParameter("user");
                            }

                            logWriter.writeLog(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED,
                                    new LogRequest("Login denied", username, LocalDateTime.now()));

                        }));
        return http.build();
}
```

the .authenticationEntryPoint method handles the 401 Unauthorized Error.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: YOu enabled both basic and login form. Your authenticationentrypoint should redirect to the login page. You shouildn't use a authentication entry point to do the logging you want, write an `ApplicationListener` instead that recevies event failures for failed authentication events.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, makes sense. Although when i try to redirect to the login page using authenticationentrypoint I get too many redirects error since the Unauthorized exception is caught over and over again.

Comment: You need to allow `/login` als it will be caught by the `/**` which requires a user, which will redirect to `/login`, which requires a user, which will rediect (well you probably get the drift).